# Touch Listener interferes with RecyclerView Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app looks like this:

[image]

Basically a FrameLayout for hosting Fragments and Bottom Nav View. Now I would like to implement right swipe gesture in HomeFragment (when Home tab is selected). But that fragment hosts a RecyclerView. To add right swipe, I am using:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

When I add this touch listener to RecyclerView, scrolling doesn't happen smoothly. I don't know the reason behind this. Please explain if you have.

Now please suggest what should I do to overcome the issue. Is there any other way to set touch listener and gesture listener so that scrolling isn't hampered as well as I can detect swipe right gesture.

As a workaround, I tried setting a full transparent view above recyclerview and that detects gesture but recyclerview doesn't scroll.

Comment: i don't understand , you want to add listener on recyclerview or frame layout?

Comment: @Avinash Basically I want to add this on HomeFragment. So be it on RV or FrameLayout. I just want that when user swipes right in that particular fragment, I get an event.

Comment: recycler view  showing on each fragment?

Comment: @Avinash No, just one fragment.

Comment: Are you placing the touch listener on the RecyclerView itself or on each view holder (or somewhere else)?

Comment: @Cheticamp RecyclerView

Comment: You need to work with ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the listener on the view that you expand in *onCreateViewHold()*. Something like

```
public @NonNull
RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_message, parent, false);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(view.getContext()));
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}
```

Remove the listener from the RecyclerView itself.

Comment: Well that worked, although I had to add the listener to most of the views also. Since the project is big, I would be looking to test this approach more for stability and will then award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want but to use swipe left or right feature in android fragments. You can can set current page to the last page using viewPager.setCurrentItem() in your MainActivity. The ViewPager is the widget that allows the user to swipe left or right to see an entirely new screen. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I know this but problem is the main screen is an Activity and not in fragment otherwise I could easily put them in ViewPager and navigation would have been handled. The codebase is so big that I'm refraining from changing the main screen from activity to fragment.

Comment: so you are using activity instead of fragments for all your items in your bottom navigation?

Comment: No. For those items, I am using Fragments while for the complete view, I am using activity. So basically inside the Activity, I have views plus Bottom Nav View. For using ViewPager, this whole thing should be a fragment I guess.

Comment: yes that is how it should be. You have an Activity and in that activity you can have multiple fragments. If that's how your setup is, all you need is a viewpager which you initialise inside your activity class which hosts all the fragments. Then if you use setCurrentItem() method you can swipe left or right in those fragments inside that activity. I hope I made sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can just change your FrameLayout with ViewPager, and add a listener for swipe action

**change FrameLayout to ViewPager**

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

**Implement PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int fragmentNumber;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int fragmentNumber) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentNumber = fragmentNumber;
}

/**
 * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
 *
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment3();
        case 3:
            return new Fragment4();
        case 4:
            return new Fragment5();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


/**
 * Return the number of views available.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentNumber;
}
}
```

**MainActivity Logic**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), 5); //Change the number based on the number of Fragments you have
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // put your scrolling logic here. use positionOffset and position to determine the next destination
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

you can also connect your viewPager with bottomNavigation for consistency
and these code can be impoved based on your specific case:kepping track of the non visible Fragments instead of distorying them .....

I hope this was helpfull.